# How to set height/width in iframe using class?

Tags: css

Why doesn't the following iframe adhere to these class rules?

```
<script type='text/css'> 
.videodimensions{height:480;width:240};
</script>

<iframe class="videodimensions" src="" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen showinfo="0"></iframe>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v8zDr/1/

Comment: You put the CSS in the JavaScript box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/v8zDr/5/

```
.videodimensions{height:480px;width:240px;}
```

paste the css to the css box and add 'px' after your width - height numbers

Answer (score 4):

Try adding some units to the css definition

```
.videodimensions{height:480px; width:240px}
```

also the semicolon at the end is unecesary. and as previously mentioned by someone your css is in the wrong box on the fiddle